# Outlook Converting CSS Button Into Image

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have created a button in HTML for outlook with CSS styling:

```
<!--Join Meeting Button-->
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <!--[if mso]>
                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="${meetingUrl}" style="height:50px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;" arcsize="50%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ad122a">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center>
            <![endif]-->
            <a href="${meetingUrl}" style="background-color:#ad122a;font-family: sans-serif; border-radius:25px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-size:17px;line-height:50px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:250px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Join Meeting</a>
            <!--[if mso]>
                </center>
                </v:roundrect>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And it looks fine in the draft email, but when I send the email, the Join Meeting Button is displayed as an image, as if converted, and the link does not work. The link works fine in the draft email using CTRL + Click.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm having the exact same issue, and it's driving me nuts :)

Comment: I believe it is down to how outlook decides to render the HTML. It uses Microsoft word as it's rendering engine - which is frustrating and confusing. In the end, I just gave up on it. The amount of work and effort was just not worth it in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Outlook desktop apps convert buttons into image.
please your following code for perfect style of button on every email client.

```
    <!--[if mso]><a href="${meetingUrl}" target="_blank">
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" stripoVmlButton href="${meetingUrl}" 
                style="height:41px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:131px;" arcsize="61%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#ad122a">
        <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
        <center style='color:#ffffff;font-family:arial, "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;'>Join Meeting</center>
    </v:roundrect></a>
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- --><span class="msohide es-button-border" style="border-radius: 0px; border-width: 0px; background:#ad122a; border-color: #ad122a;"><a class="es-button" href="${meetingUrl}" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 25px;" target="_blank">Join Meeting</a></span>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

Or you can use this site to create buttons https://buttons.cm/